# Random split function in spark ml produces a train test split of different number of rows each time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to split a dataframe into train and test with 70% rows in train and 30% rows in test. I am using `randomSplit` function from **spark.ml** in **scala**. I do not want to use a seed because I need a different train and test set each time I run the code.

The issue is that the function produces different number of rows in train and test each time the code is run. However the issue doesn't occur when I use a seed.

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?

```
val Array(trainData, testData) = dfForModel.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))

Number of rows in dfForModel = 1442

Outputs:
Run number 1
Number of rows in train =  1025
Number of rows in test = 417

Run number 2
Number of rows in train =  993
Number of rows in test = 449

Run number 3
Number of rows in train =  1011
Number of rows in test = 431

Run number 4
Number of rows in train =  1003
Number of rows in test = 439

Run number 5
Number of rows in train =  989
Number of rows in test = 453
```

I am using count function in spark-scala to count the number of rows for example: `dfForModel.count`.

Answer (score 0):

This hapenned to me too.

I do not think that there is a bug, some approximations must have been done for the cases when the number of elements in your data cannot be divided into a Integer number of elements (this is not your case). For example in your case, the amount of data has as divisors 7 and 3, but if that is not the case the  function must approximate.

Myself I split the data and saved it afterwards in order to have the same training/test dataset for different tests and measures.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the function produces different number of rows in
>   train and test each time the code is run. However the issue doesn't
>   occur when I use a seed.
>
> Is this a bug or an expected behaviour?

***This is expected behaviour not bug.***

[if you see the randomsplit code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.scala#L144), ***even if you are not providing the seed it will take random long `Utils.random.nextLong` as seed***. and calls the functions internally.

```
/**
   * Randomly splits this Dataset with the provided weights.
   *
   * @param weights weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1.
   * @group typedrel
   * @since 2.0.0
   */
  def randomSplit(weights: Array[Double]): Array[Dataset[T]] = {
    randomSplit(weights, Utils.random.nextLong)
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a expected behaviour from a user perspective. I would defnitely expect to always have the same amount of rows in the resulting dataframes. dfForModel.count() * 0.7 and dfForModel.count() * 0.3 will always be the same exact number. You may round it up or down, but always with the same criterion...